# Two things about SQL which I don't really understand

Tags: php, sql

I have this query inside a PHP file:

```
return $this->_getDb()->fetchRow('
SELECT *
FROM xf_user
WHERE user_id = ?
', $userId);
```

What does the last line do , and after a quick look up on google I found that a question mark is a dynamic parameter. Can anybody give me a more detailed explanation about it? Thanks.

Comment: You should show more code context.  It looks like perhaps you are using a non-standard database library?

Comment: This is one thing - what's the other thing about SQL you don't understand? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>Well, you're missing part of the command (notice the unbalanced quote).  I suspect you left off one or two lines at the beginning.</s>  (User edited the post to include the missing line).

What a parameter does is take the parameter's value (the value held in the $userID variable) and use it to evaluate the SQL Query.  So, if $userID contained the value 101, the query executed would basically be `SELECT * FROM xf_user WHERE user_id = 101`.

However, using parameters is different from simply constructing the query as a text statement, since parameters are type checked and are safe against SQL injection attacks.  Also, the same command executed multiple times with a new value in $userID will execute faster since the SQL engine can "prepare" the statement just once rather than each time you execute it.

Comment: Wow thank you!  How would I make a SQL query execute in PHP if a variable is equal to a string? ( text )

Comment: If the user_id column in the database is a string, just make sure that $userID contains a string value (I assumed that they were both integers in my example, but as long as they're both compatible types it works fine).  If, however, user_id in the database is an integer and $userID contains a string, just convert $userID to integer with whatever function PHP offers for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are working with a prepared statement.  The allows you to "prepare" a query expecting dynamic parameters to be passed to it on the MySQL server.  You then send necessary parameters in a separate operation.

THis can provide some performance benefit, but also gives a huge security benefit in preventing SQL injection attacks.

Though it looks liek you are not using MySQLI, you might read PHP mysqli::prepare documentation for more background info:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php